# Error on passing down function with argument to grandchild in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have the following code:
My main component is something like this:

```
class Layout extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state={
      searchValue: ''
    }
  }
  getSearchValue(searchValue){
    this.setState({searchValue})
  }
  ...
   return 
     <Filter
       getSearchValue={this.getSearchValue.bind(this)}
     />
  ...
}
```

Then I have a child, called Filter:

```
class Filter extends React.Component {
  ...
  return
     <SearchBar
        getSearchValue={this.props.getSearchValue}
     />
  ...
}
```

And finally the Search component itself:

```
class SearchBar extends React.Component {

   handleEvent(e){
     this.props.getSearchValue(e.target.value)
   }
   ...
   return
      <input onChange={this.handleEvent.bind(this)}/>

}
```

Now, I am pretty sure I had something like this but then I messed it up, and tried to do it back, but now I get an error message:

Uncaught TypeError: this.props.getSearchValue is not a function

Are any of my bindings wrong? I tried several times.

If I put a console.log('Hi') and delete the this.setState() from my getSearchValue in Layout, and I do not pass a variable in SearchBar to this.props.getSearchValue, I get the message to the console. So the function works, but only without arguments. Why?

Comment: in which component do you exactly get the error? this code looks OK, can you give more code of your components?

Comment: at SearchBar.value

Comment: I'm suspecting the missing `super()` in the constructer may cause this

Comment: The code is just an excerpt. The super is there.

Comment: Oh I see, try doing the bind in Layout's constructor instead - `this.getSearchValue = this.getSearchValue.bind(this)`, and remove the bind in `SearchBar`, it's not needed there.

Comment: I had it like that before, and worked well. I tried, your solution does not lead to more problems, but does not solve the original one either.

Answer (score 0):

The coding is correct, except the extra ) in the below statement:

```
 <Filter
   getSearchValue={this.getSearchValue.bind(this))}
 />
```

Otherwise, there may be issue in other area of the codes.

Comment: I have tried the same, and I can really able to call the setState function. There is no issue to pass the functions to the grandchild in this way.